# Why do my AWS SQS messages not get deleted?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS SQS queue which receives the messages, iterates through them printing the details and then I attempt to delete them.  Unfortunately they are not deleting even though I get a success response.  I can't figure out why they are not being removed when I am sure I've used similar code before.

The basic example I'm trying is like this:

```
import boto3

# Create SQS client
sqs = boto3.client('sqs',
                    region_name='',
                    aws_access_key_id='',
                    aws_secret_access_key=''
                    )

queue_url = ''

# Receive message from SQS queue
response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    AttributeNames=[
        'All'
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
    MessageAttributeNames=[
        'All'
    ],
    VisibilityTimeout=0,
    WaitTimeSeconds=0
)

print(len(response['Messages']))

for index, message in enumerate(response['Messages']):
    print("Index Number: ", index)
    print(message)

    receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']

    # do some function

    sqs.delete_message(
         QueueUrl=queue_url,
         ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you are using `VisibilityTimeout=0`. This means that the message immediately goes back to the SQS queue. So there is nothing to delete for you.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the response.  This definitely make no difference when I set VisibilityTimeout=20.  I still get a seemingly random number of messages returned 3 then 6 then 9 then 3 then 9 then 3 again, not the expected 10. How do I need to change the code to retrieve the 10 (out of 11) available messages, print the contents to the screen and then delete that message from the queue pls?  Assume no changes or external functions.  I just don't understand.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnBoy I can't see anything other wrong with your code. How many messages do you have in the queue? Maybe you keep getting new batch all the time, not previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `VisibilityTimeout=0` and `WaitTimeSeconds=0` - the message will timeout and become visible again after zero seconds.

This is probably not what you want - you should try with higher values here and read the docs about them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html

You can time out the usual processing time and set the values to safe ones, so that messages will be delivered in case of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Key points to understand regarding SQS:

1. Visibility timeout
2. Wait time seconds
3. Receipt handle

When a message is received by a Lambda function, it gets a 'ReceiptHandle' for that receive.
Now, this `ReceiveHandle` changes whenever a new lambda thread receives the message making the previous handler invalid.

Since `VisibilityTimeout = 0` and `WaitTimeSeconds = 0`,(as pointed out by @Mandraenke), the message is immediately made available to another lambda thread with a new 'ReceiptHandle'.

The receipt 'ReceiptHandle' being processed by the previous lambda thread becomes invalid and could not be reached by the lambda function processing it.